# How to use FILTER function to extract data from not exact matches?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In this table I've got events schedule in the first two columns (A, B) and a list of events in the other two (C, D). What I need my table to do is gather all hours of the events provided in column A - which I managed to do already with the FILTER function - it takes the title from column C, looks for it in column B and gives the hours from column A. Which works great, but only if the titles from column C are exactly the same as in column B.

| A: Time | B: Event | / | C: Event | D: Times |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 10.00 | XYZ | / | XYZ | 10.00, 11.00 |
| 10.30 | ABC | / | ABC | 10.30, 11.30 |
| 11.00 | SPECIAL: XYZ | / |  |  |
| 11.30 | ABC | / |  |  |

So what I'm struggling with is how to make it find the hour of the event even if the title is not **exactly** the same as in column C. Sometimes in the schedule I need to put some extra information, before or after the title of the event.
If that's of any help, these adnotations before the titles would always end with a colon (as above in the sample table) and if they're after a title they'd always be in brackets (so like **XYZ (special)**).

I found how to extract the title after the colons, but the formula in column D has to filter a range of cells (over 150) so making it look through each and every one row would make the formula miles long.

I don't want to put an extra column to extract the title and then make the formula look through those because the file is already heavy with sheets and formulas and takes a while to load on some of my teammates computers, so adding more formulas and data would make it even slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try:

```
=map(D2:D,lambda(Σ,if(Σ="",,ifna(textjoin(", ",1,filter(A:A,search(Σ,B:B)))))))
```

[image]